Preserving custom form fields when converting issue to project
I am converting issues to projects, but want to preserve the custom forms values selected by the requester when converting to project. I know we have Options
"options": [
"preserveIssue",
"preservePrimaryContact"
],
but how to I add custom form values here ?
Suggest proper syntax for adding "SM - Primary contact for request questions" for example.
